# Arrays taking each others values?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, element

Trying to write this program for a bit of fun, but its giving me some major grief. Everything works fine if I just toss my function one case, however when I move onto 2+ cases at a time, they start taking values from each other. The first function swaps it last element (after sorting) with the first element of the second function (before sorting).

Example: valuesOne and valuesTwo should be [3, 5, 9, 27, 31] and [1, 1, 5, 6, 18, 102] respectively. However they end up as [1, 3, 5, 9, 27] and [1, 5, 6, 18, 31, 102] respectively. Can anyone help me with this? I feel that it may be a problem with my pointer but I'm only just starting to learn that now.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int doubleMedian(int *values, int numValues);

int main() {
    int valuesOne[5] = {5, 31, 3, 9, 27};
    int valuesTwo[6] = {1, 6, 18, 1, 102, 5};

    int resultOne = doubleMedian(valuesOne, 5);
    int resultTwo = doubleMedian(valuesTwo, 6);

    printf("Double medians are %d and %d", resultOne, resultTwo);
}

int doubleMedian(int *values, int numValues) {
    int temp = 0, pass = 0, medianNum = 0, median = 0;

    printf("Before sort:\t");

    for(int x = 0; x < numValues; x++) {
        printf("%d, ", values[x]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    while(pass < numValues) {
        for(int x = 0; x < numValues; x++) {
            if(values[x] > values[x + 1]) {
                temp = values[x];
                values[x] = values[x + 1];
                values[x + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        pass++;
    }

    printf("After sort:\t");

    for(int x = 0; x < numValues; x++) {
        printf("%d, ", values[x]);
    }

    if(numValues % 2 == 0) {
        medianNum = (numValues / 2) - 1;
        median = values[medianNum + 1] + values[medianNum];
    } else {
        medianNum = (numValues / 2) - 1;
        median = values[medianNum] * 2;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return median;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an off-by-one problem in your sorting loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x < numValues; x++)
```

should be

```
for(int x = 0; x < numValues-1; x++)
```

because you are referencing an item at `x+1`. This item is past the end of the array passed in, so accessing it is undefined behavior. Very often undefined behavior does not return in an exception. Instead, an unexpected value pops in at some seemingly random spot. In this case, it looks like you are reading the first element of the second array due to the memory layout produced by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks heaps, not going to lie, that isn't the first time I've made  a silly off-by-one mistake tonight, haha. Cheers!

Edit: Great explanation as well, it is indeed.

Comment: As @dasblinkenlight said, you come over the memory address of array1 and read the value of array 2. Because both arrays are placed on the stack behind each other. So you read from the memory of array2 ;)